# How to submit a button when the form becomes visible

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im trying to send the user to a payment URL if the user validate is true and that works fine.

but i have another form thats hidden from the beginning and if the validate is true i unhide the form and then i need the btn with id #openPaymentButton to get sbumitted

```
 if(data.success == true)
                            {
                                //Vis betalings vindue knap og klik på knappen
                                $scope.hideEpayBtn = false;
                                $("#openPaymentButton").click();
                                console.log('virker');

                            } else {
                                alert("Error");
                            }



<form action="https://ssl.ditonlinebetalingssystem.dk/integration/ewindow/Default.aspx" ng-if="hideEpayBtn == false" method="post">
    <input ng-hide="hideEpayBtn" id="openPaymentButton" type="submit" value="">


</form>
```

Comment: I have tried that now, but it still not working :/

Comment: If i remove ng-if="hideEpayBtn == false" on the form, it submit it.. but i need to hide the form so no one can manipulate with the price

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. I dont see any price in your question form, so how can they possibly change the price, when it's not even shown? or didnt you include all the html you have?

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do, do you want to automatically submit the form if the validation has succeeded?

Comment: Dennis Havent included all the form inputs @Celt Yes thats what i want :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all the question is not clear. So far I understand, you are talking about some validation.

If you question bit specific, I can give you an appropriate answer. This answer is from my guess based on your question.

May be you can use something like this in your form

```
<form name="formName" data-ng-submit="yourfunction(formName.$valid)" novalidate>

<button type="submit" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">Submit</button>

</form>

<form action="https://ssl.ditonlinebetalingssystem.dk/integration/ewindow/Default.aspx"
 data-ng-hide="success == false" method="post">

<input data-ng-hide="success == ''" id="openPaymentButton" type="submit" value="">
</form>
```

In you angular controller:

```
$scope.success = false;
$scope.yourfunction= function (isValid) {
    if (isValid) {
            $scope.success = true;
            serviceFor.addNewProject($scope.inputObject);

        }
    } else {
        $scope.success = true;
        $scope.failMessage = "Please fill up all the fields";
    }
};
```

This is my best guess for what you are asking for. Please let me know if it is ok.

Comment: I have edited my questing so its more clear i hope :)

Comment: is my answer is applicable ?

Comment: <form action="https://ssl.ditonlinebetalingssystem.dk/integration/ewindow/Default.aspx"> data-ng-hide="success == false" method="post">
             <input data-ng-hide="success == false" id="openPaymentButton" type="submit" value="">
        </form>

Comment: Yay Thanks so much ! i added this too, to get it to submit the form $("#openPaymentButton").click();

Comment: A little problem is that the form is visible in the developer tool inspector, so the user can manipulate with the price right now :/

Comment: when i use ng-show="success == true" it works fine, but then people can see it in the source code, but if i use ng-if it works but will not submit the form :S

Comment: Yeah i tried that too, and it show the btn right but my "jquery" $("#openPaymentButton").click(); just dont click the btn :S

Comment: i think its because its not yet loaded in the DOM, because their ng-ifs expressions have not been parsed yet.